# Sql Server 2008 decimal(10,2) divides the inserted value by 100

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I have this column that looks like this in a table `DECIMAL(10,2)` and a stored procedure that inserts rows in that table. The parameter for that column looks like this `@FuelLiters AS DECIMAL(10, 2),`
I call this stored procedure using ado.net. The sql parameter for that column looks like this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(@FuelLiters, SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = fuelLiters; 
(it's decimal value)
```

Whatever i do sql is modifying my value so it has 2 decimals. If fuelLiters = 56 it will save in the database 0.56. If fuelLiters = 75.4 it will save in the database 7.54.

What am i doing wrong?

My sql parameter now looks like this, but still the same problem.

```
            SqlParameter fuelParam = new SqlParameter();
            fuelParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal;
            fuelParam.ParameterName = "@FuelLiters";                
            fuelParam.Precision = 10;
            fuelParam.Scale = 2;
            fuelParam.Value = fuelLiters ;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(fuelParam);
```

LE: I modified the sql parameter so that the value is set after precision and scale are set and i added the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveFuel] 
    @Id AS INT,
    @RegNumber AS NVARCHAR(50),
    @FuelLiters AS DECIMAL(10, 2)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Fuel]
        (
            [Id],       
            [RegNumber],
            [Fuel_litres]         
        )
        VALUES
        (
            @Id,
            @RegNumber,
            @FuelLiters
        )

END
```

ok, i am stupid, there is a trigger i didn't notice which was doing some *corrections* on that field

Comment: "What am i doing wrong?" - something, in some code you've not shown us.

Comment: code apperar correct at a first glance, does the store procedure do some extra work ?

Comment: Shouldn't you set Precision and Scale before setting the Value?

Comment: @IvoTops - I was looking into that also, but the value gets stored in an internal member (`SqlValue`) that maintains its own precision and scale values, and any necessary conversion only appears to take place when the parameter is actually sent to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the precision and scale of the SqlParameter. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a10hy4y.aspx